# Compression rate in Spark Application

Tags: apache-spark, serialization, compression, benchmarking

I am doing some benchmark in a cluster using Spark. Among the various things I want to get a good approximation of the average size reduction achieved by serialization and compression. I am running in client deploy-mode and with the local master, and tired with both shells of versions 1.6 and 2.2 of spark.

I want to do that calculating the in-memory size and then the size on disk, so the fraction should be my answer. I have obviously no problems getting the on-disk size, but I am really struggling with the in-memory one.

Since my RDD is made of doubles and they occupy 8 bytes each in memory I tried counting the number of elements in the RDD and multiplying by 8, but that leaves out a lot of things.
The second approach was using "SizeEstimator" (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$
), but this is giving me crazy results! In Spark 1.6 it is either 30, 130 or 230 randomly (47 MB on disk), in Spark 2.2 it starts at 30 and everytime I execute it it increases by 0 or by 1. I know it says it's not super accurate but I can't even find a bit of consistency! I even tried setting persisting level in memory only
rdd.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
but still, nothing changed.

Is there any other way I can get the in-memory size of the RDD? Or should I try another approach? I am writing to disk with rdd.SaveAsTextFile, and generating the rdd via RandomRDDs.uniformRDD.

**EDIT**

sample code:

write

```scala
val rdd = RandomRDDs.uniformRDD(sc, nBlocks, nThreads)
rdd.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)
println("RDD count: " + rdd.count)
rdd.saveAsObjectFile("file:///path/to/folder")
```

read

```scala
val rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles(name,nThreads)
rdd.count() //action so I'm sure the file is actually read
```

[webUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsGMv.jpg)

Comment: Are you trying to get the size of each rdd ?

Comment: Yes, I want to get the in-memory size of a single RDD and then compare it to the sum of its partitions' size on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Try caching the rdd as you mentioned and check in the storage tab of the spark UI.

By default rdd is deserialised and stored in memory. If you want to serialise it then specifically use persist with option MEMORY_ONLY_SER.The memory consumption will be less. In disk data always will be stored in serialised fashion

Check once the spark UI

Comment: For the spark UI the jobs I am launching do not appear them, since they have deploy-mode client.
As for the MEMORY_ONLY_2 the documentation says 
"Same as the levels above, but replicate each partition on two cluster nodes. ", so I guess you were talking about MEMORY_ONLY_SER, but again I want the in memory not to be serialized, and the one on disk to be serialized.

Comment: It’s my bad it’s _ser. The disk data will automatically be serliazed. If job has to be present in UI. Check your master machine up with port 4040.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, checking the web UI on port 4040 works in client mode, and I can see "Input" and "Output" sizes in "saveAsObjectFile". That said the in-memory size with MEMORY_ONLY and MEMORY_ONLY_SER doesn't change, and the Input size is always smaller than the output, meaning that when saved on disk it occupies more space. Is that how it should work? I thoght it would occupy less storage on disk with compression and serialization.

Comment: With serialisation it should take less memory. Please paste your spark UI storage tab and sample code

Comment: I edited the post! Let me know and thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Spark UI link is navigating to some other link. Please check. Why you have same rdd variable defined twice. Do you want to use whole text file as it will take read one file as a whole with key as file name.

Comment: Spark UI works for me, is an Imgur link. The code snippets are from 2 different functions, I have changed the formatting a bit so it's more clear. The wholeTextFiles reads all the files in the folder into a single rdd.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#wholeTextFiles-java.lang.String-int-

Comment: Yeah still the spark UI page is going to the image uploading website. Please check once